# How do make a script for show previous text fields with value and add new text fields until answer is correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textfield

**" I need a script to create new TEXt-FIELDS and also display the previous Text-Fields with Value and Message. "**

- If press BUTTON, check text-field value.
- If value is 100, then script functions are OVER.
- Otherwise, create new text-fields with entered VALUE and MESSAGE until get the right answer.

I try with "document.createTextNode();" but this method cannot call ID value

---

**Click below the LINK to see image**

### [I need script for this kind of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Ze8.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="num1" type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" required>
<input id="num2" type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" required>
<input id="num3" type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" required>

<p id="ans" ></p>
<p id="a" ></p>
<p id="b" ></p>
<p id="c" ></p>


<script>
function myFunction() {
var x, y, z, text;

var a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
var b = document.getElementById("num2").value;
var c = document.getElementById("num3").value;   

x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
y = document.getElementById("num2").value;
z = document.getElementById("num3").value;

if (x,y,z == 1 && y == 0 && z == 0) {
    text = "Right Ans.";
} else {
    text = "Wrong Ans.";
}

document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = text;
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = a;
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = b;
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = c;


}
</script>

<button type="button"  onclick=myFunction()> Check </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The tags have been edited, but in the future, please remember that Java and JavaScript are entirely different languages; other than being programming languages, they have pretty much nothing in common.

Comment: You are asking for a solution development which in not appropriate. This is a [Q&A site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this working example.

```js
var IsCorrectAns=false;
function myFunction() {
  if(IsCorrectAns==false)
  {
    var x, y, z, text;

    x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    y = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    z = document.getElementById("num3").value;

    if (x == 1 && y == 0 && z == 0) {
        text = "Right Ans.";
        $("#divAnsInput").hide();
        IsCorrectAns=true;
    } else {
        text = "Wrong Ans.";
        $("#num1").val("");
        $("#num2").val("");
        $("#num3").val("");
    }

    var ansHTML="<div class='AnsSnippet'>"+              
                "<p><span>"+x+"</span>&nbsp;<span>"+y+"</span>&nbsp;<span>"+z+"</span></p>"+
                " <p>"+text+"</p>"+
                "</div>";

    $("#divIns").append(ansHTML);
  }
  else
  {
        IsCorrectAns=false;
        $("#num1").val("");
        $("#num2").val("");
        $("#num3").val("");
        $("#divIns").html("");
        $("#divAnsInput").show();
  }
}
```

```css
.AnsSnippet span {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 3px 18px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divIns">
  
</div>
<div id="divAnsInput">
  <input id="num1" type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" required>
  <input id="num2" type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" required>
  <input id="num3" type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" required>
</div>


<button type="button"  onclick=myFunction()> Check </button>
```

Comment: thank you very much, mr.Bharat. I am really satisfied with you script :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pure JavaScript way to get it done:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AmitKB/e14n3qqq/2/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
  
<!-- Template is hidden -->
<div id="ansTemplate" style="display:none">
  <div class="tryAns">
    <input class="inputA" type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" required>
    <input class="inputB" type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" required>
    <input class="inputC" type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" required>
    <h3 class="ansResult"></h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="ansPane">

</div>
<button onClick="checkAns()">
Check
</button>
<script>
var elAnsTemplate = document.getElementById('ansTemplate');
var elAnsPane = document.getElementById('ansPane');

function nextAnswerInput(){
  elAnsPane.innerHTML += elAnsTemplate.innerHTML;
  
}

function findLastAnswerPane(){
 // all asnwer pane
  var allAnswerPane = document.querySelectorAll('.tryAns');
  
  // last answer pane
  latestAnswerPane = allAnswerPane[ allAnswerPane.length - 1 ];
  
  return latestAnswerPane;
}

function getAnsParts(){
 
  // Get last answer pane
  var latestAnswerPane = findLastAnswerPane();
  
 // Read parts from last answer
  var a = latestAnswerPane.querySelector('.inputA').value,
   b = latestAnswerPane.querySelector('.inputB').value,
   c = latestAnswerPane.querySelector('.inputC').value;

 return [a, b, c]
}

function setAnsResult( ansText ){
  // Get last answer pane
  var latestAnswerPane = findLastAnswerPane();

 latestAnswerPane.querySelector('.ansResult').innerText = ansText;
}

function nextTryInput(){
  var newTryElement = document.createElement('div');
  newTryElement.innerHTML = elAnsTemplate.innerHTML;
  elAnsPane.appendChild( newTryElement );
}

function handleRightAnswer(){
 setAnsResult( 'Right' );
}
function handleWrongAnswer(){
  setAnsResult('Wrong');
  nextTryInput();
}
function checkAns(){
 var ansParts = getAnsParts();
   ansA = ansParts[0],
    ansB = ansParts[1],
    ansC = ansParts[2];
  
  if ( ansA === '1' && ansB === '0' && ansC === '0' ){
   handleRightAnswer();
  }
  else{
   handleWrongAnswer();
  }
}
</script>

<script>
 // Show first input
  nextTryInput();
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much, mr.AmitKB. I am really satisfied with you script :)

Comment: yes, I try to mark. but I can mark one solution only. not more. but I want to mark both 3. Because these 3 solutions are working well. So I am pending with my mark. what do I do to mark both 3 solutions? pls tell me @AmitKB

Answer (score 0):

A variation on a theme perhaps - again, pure Javascript with a little css too.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>numbers</title>
        <style>
            body{
                counter-reset:choices;
            }
            body,body *{
                font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;
                font-size:0.9rem;
                box-sizing:border-box;
            }
            .choices{
                margin:1rem;
                padding:1rem;
                border:1px dotted gray;
                clear:both;
                float:left;
                width:40%;
                text-align:center;
                counter-increment:choices;
            }
            .choices h1{
                font-size:1.2rem;
                text-decoration:underline;
            }
            .choices h1:after{
                display:inline-block;
                clear:both;
                text-decoration:underline;
                color:red;
                content:counter( choices )
            }

            input[type='number']{
                background:#ffffb7;
                width:5rem;
                text-align:center;
                padding:0.5rem;
                margin:0.25rem 1rem;
            }
            input[type='button']{
                float:left;
                clear:both;
            }
            .answer,
            .answered{
                width:5rem;
                clear:none;
                float:none;
                border:1px solid black;
                display:inline-block;
                margin:0.25rem 1rem;
                padding:1rem 0.5rem;
            }
            .answer:first-of-type,
            .answered:first-of-type{
                width:100%;
                clear:both;
                margin:0.5rem auto!important;
                border:none;
            }
            .correct{
                background-color:#bff4c0!important;
            }
            .incorrect{
                background-color:#ffb9b9!important;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function myfunction( event ){
                try{
                    var bttn=document.getElementById( 'btn' );
                    var inputs=document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="number"][name^="num_"]' );
                    var answers=document.querySelectorAll( 'p[class="answer"]' );
                    var guess=[];
                    var regex = /^\d+$/;

                    inputs.forEach( function(e){
                        if( regex.test( e.value ) ) guess.push( e.value.toString() );
                        else throw new Error('Numeric input only');
                    });


                    if( guess.join('')=='100' ){

                        answers[0].innerHTML='Correct answer';
                        answers[0].className='correct';
                        setclasses.call(this,'correct');
                        bttn.disabled=true;

                    } else {

                        var choices=document.querySelectorAll( 'div.choices:last-of-type' )[0];
                        var clone=choices.cloneNode( true );
                        clearvalues.call( this, clone );

                        answers[ 0 ].innerHTML='Wrong answer';
                        answers[ 0 ].className='answered';


                        for( var i=1; i <= inputs.length; i++ ){
                            try{
                                answers[ i ].className='answered incorrect';
                                answers[ i ].innerHTML=inputs[ i-1 ].value;

                                inputs[ i-1 ].name='guess_'+( i + 1 );
                                inputs[ i-1 ].className='incorrect';

                            }catch( err ){
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        choices.parentNode.insertBefore( clone, bttn );
                    }
                }catch( err ){
                    answers[0].innerHTML=err;
                }
            }
            function clearvalues( clone ){
                var inputs=clone.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="number"][name^="num_"]' );
                var answers=clone.querySelectorAll( 'p[class="answer"]' );
                inputs.forEach(function(e){e.value=''});
                answers.forEach(function(e){e.innerHTML=''});
            }
            function setclasses(c){
                document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="number"][name^="num_"],p[class="answer"]' ).forEach(function(e){console.log(e);e.className=c});
            }
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                document.getElementById('btn').onclick=myfunction;
            },false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='choices'>
            <h1>Choices: </h1>
            <input name="num_1" type="number" size=1 maxlength=1 required value=2 />
            <input name="num_2" type="number" size=1 maxlength=1 required value=0 />
            <input name="num_3" type="number" size=1 maxlength=1 required value=0 />
            <div class='answers'>
                <p class="answer"></p>
                <p class="answer"></p>
                <p class="answer"></p>
                <p class="answer"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" id='btn' value='Check' />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much, mr.RamRaider. I am really satisfied with you script and also nice Program STYLE :)

Comment: hey! your code is awesome. but it has main concept mistake that have to must declare multiple variables like " var x, y, z, text; ". but you used  " var guess=[]; "  only.  then How do I use "if else"  ?. please solve this one issue. Tanq!